# Freeze with "USE_AUTH_EMULATOR not set." in Unity2022.3.11 using firebase cloud functions

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine

I was using Firebase cloud functions in Unity2022.3.11 and got an error "USE_AUTH_EMULATOR not set." and froze.

What is this and what is needed to prevent the error from occurring?

Unitypackage has been installed. And written codes like that.

```
FirebaseFunctions func;
FirebaseAuth auth;


        await FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            if(task.Result == DependencyStatus.Available)
            {
        auth = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
                func = FirebaseFunctions.DefaultInstance;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log(task.Result.ToString());
                return;
            }
        });
        try
        {
            if(auth.CurrentUser.UserId == null)
            {
                await auth.SignInAnonymouslyAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log($"Already auth {auth.CurrentUser.UserId}");
            }
        }

var task = func.GetHttpsCallable("task").CallAsync(idToken);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that it is an error? The Firebase Unity SDK is built on top of the Firebase C++ SDK, which [logs "USE_AUTH_EMULATOR not set" at the Info level](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-cpp-sdk/blob/b5b7e05b6a6e3c7ca4baadb7f15ef6fc6f36829c/auth/src/desktop/rpcs/auth_request.cc#L87-L91).

If `USE_AUTH_EMULATOR` is not set, the SDK logs that message and connects to the live Firebase Auth service. If it has any other value, the Firebase Auth Emulator is connected instead, based on the relevant configuration (defaults to `localhost:9099` at time of writing).

That log message is no cause for alarm.

If your application has frozen, there is something else that is the cause.

Comment: Thank you. If you can figure it out, could you please tell me why it froze?

Comment: @ChocoNaak There's nothing obvious from what you've provided, but your code doesn't have any error handling. Add some catch blocks and check if your tasks have actually completed successfully inside your `ContinueWith` calls (using `Task.IsCompletedSuccessfully`) to see if you can discern any more information.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer. I just forgot to add 'async'.

```
await func.GetHttpsCallable("task").CallAsync(idToken).ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            return task.Result.Data.ToString();
        });

        return "";
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).